# Access denied error when users attempt to start site workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a SharePoint 2013 site workflow on SharePoint online. I have customized the initiation form (WFInitForm.aspx) to add some javascript to ensure two parameters are filled in by the user.

The user can see the workflow in the Site Workflows page but gets Access Denied when attempting to navigate to the initiation form. The user is a member of a group with Contribute rights on the site. The same user can start a workflow without an initiation form.

I am a site collection administrator and can start the workflow without errors.

What do I need to change so "Contribute" level users can start the workflow?

Comment: User with Contribute permission on the site cannot start the workflow manually, is it right? Does this user have proper permissions on the list/library where you run the workflow? User must have the Edit Items permission to start a workflow. Some workflows may require that user also has the Manage Lists permission, or another specific permission, to start a workflow on a document or item. Give user Edit permission on the list/library and compare the results. Also, ensure user has Contribute permission on the workflow tasks list.

Comment: This is a site workflow. I will check out the other suggestions, thanks!